# flyout menu examples?

Tags: jquery, menu, flyout, css

Is it possible to make a menu that will drop the child elements below when you hover on the parent and then when you hover on the child it flys out?

Something like this but obviously goes down on hover of parent.

http://www.vision.to/simple-css-one-level-flyout-menu.php

edit: could you show me an example of a menu based on my description. I would like to learn how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Something like an accodrion menu?

Comment: could you show me how i can do this? any examples?

Comment: google: "Vertical accordion menu"

Comment: the vertical accordion menu is nice but it does not flyout after the 2nd level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple CSS-only Menu: http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/NKL24/8/

Comment: this looks really good but where you have the Links i need them to be submenus and then flyout. Any ideas?